# How to split the string into subsctring without using strtok?

Tags: c

In this code, the string is split by the difference of the space. I could do that through `strtok` but I didn't. I just want to know that how can split the strings by assigning tokens to them, like if I want to print the first token then it should print the first word from the string. Similarly, if I want to print the second word then it should print the second word after the first space occurred and so on.

```
int main(){
  char inputString[100], words[10][10];
  int indexCtr = 0, wordIndex = 0, totalWords = 0;

  printf("Input a string: ");
  fgets(inputString, sizeof(inputString), stdin);

  for(indexCtr = 0; indexCtr <= strlen(inputString); indexCtr++){
    if(inputString[indexCtr] == ' ' || inputString[indexCtr] == '\0'){
      words[totalWords][wordIndex] = '\0';
      totalWords++;
      wordIndex = 0;
    }
    else{
      words[totalWords][wordIndex] = inputString[indexCtr];
      wordIndex++;
    }
  }

  printf("\nWords from the string are:\n");
  for(indexCtr = 0; indexCtr < totalWords; indexCtr++){
    printf("%s\n", words[indexCtr]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as an idea with strncpy(...):

```
   char input[100] = "   1   2 3       4 5       "
                     "one    two    three    four five";

   char words[10][10] = { 0 };

   size_t w_counter = 0;

   for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen (input); i++) {
      while (input[i] != '\0' && isspace (input[i])) {
         i++;
      }

      char* start = &input[i];
      while (input[i] != '\0' && !isspace (input[i])) {
         i++;
      }

      strncpy (words[w_counter++],
               start,
               &input[i] - start);
   }
 
   //output
   for (size_t i = 0; i < w_counter; i++){
      puts (words[i]);
   }
```